# What are the alternatives to basis functions like a B-spline or polynomial?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, splines

Let $f_1, ..., f_n$ be basis functions so that we consider $F = \sum f_i \alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i \in R$ are constants.

This is what we do when we use e.g. generalized additive models.

I am currently trying to implement such models and I want to compare various choices of $f$. But what choices are commonly used?

I can take the $f$s to be the polynomials: $f_1 = 1, f_2 = x, f_3 = x^2, ...$, and I can take $f$ to be the B-spline basis, but are there are any other commonly used bases that I can use here (obviously I can use pretty much any function I want, but I am looking for what statistians usually do)?

Comment: gradient boosting is also of the form $F= \sum_i f_i\alpha_i$. There it is common to use stumps as base learneres for $f_i$

Comment: For some commonly-used and not-so-commonly-used ones you could look at the *mgcv* package for R and the bases it implements: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.terms.html